# accessing $this in extended class using namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces, this, extend

B.php:

```
class B extends A {
    function foo() {
        $this->get['id'];
    }
}
```

C.php:

```
namespace NAME;
class C extends B {
    function foo() {
        $b = new \B();
        $b->get['id'] = $params['userToken'];
    }
}
```

The above works but how to I access $this instead of creating a new instance of `B`?

If I try and access it like this:

```
namespace NAME;
class C extends B {
    function foo() {
        $this->get['id'] = $params['userToken'];
    }
}
```

It returns the error: `Using $this when not in object context`. $this is `protected` but as it C is extending B it shouldn't cause an issue and if it does, shouldn't return that error.

Comment: Since `C` extends `B` you should not instantiate `B`.  If you need to call the parent (B) `foo()`, do `parent::foo()` inside `C::foo()`.

Comment: @onetrickpony doing $this->get causes the error 'Using $this when not in object context in…'

Comment: How are you calling your `C->foo()` function, `C::foo()`?

Comment: @jeroen call_user_func() actually

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but I don't want to access foo() I want to basically do $this->get['id'] from C like is done in B

Comment: @Rudiger Your simplified example is a little too simplified. You can just directly use `$this->get['id']` in `C` since it extends `B` unless `b::$get` is `private`.  Please post more context for the code. Un-simplify it a little so we can understand how you are trying to call it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski updated the question with the error returned and how I tried to access it.

Comment: Are you sure that `function foo()` is not actually `static function foo()`? You _are_ in object context, and `$this` is valid in the code _as posted_. But we can assume there's other stuff going on you haven't posted because `$params['userToken']` isn't in scope there, for example.

Comment: It's not but I also don't want to access it, foo() is just for reference because it is calling $this, and I want to call $this in the same way. There is 3000 lines of code in B and A so showing it all isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last piece of code will work, but when you use `call_user_func()` to call a method that uses `$this` you need to pass an instance instead of the class name, i.e.

```
call_user_func([new C, 'foo']);
```

Comment: Sorry about not posting the call_user_func(), the code was someone else's and didn't think it was affecting it but it makes sense now. Cheers.